# SAS Export data to create standard and comma-delimited raw data files

Tags: sas

i m new to sas and studying different ways to do subject line task.

Here is two ways i knew at the moment

**Method1: file statement in data step**

```
  *DATA _NULL_ / FILE / PUT ;
data _null_;
    set engappeal;
    file 'C:\Users\1502911\Desktop\exportdata.txt' dlm=',';
    put id $ name $ semester scoreEng;
run;
```

**Method2: Proc Export**

```
proc export
    data = engappeal
    outfile = 'C:\Users\1502911\Desktop\exportdata2.txt'
    dbms = dlm;
    delimiter = ',';
run;
```

**Question:**

*1, Is there any alternative way to export raw data files*

*2, Is it possible to export the header also using the data step method 1*

Comment: Answer to 2.: Add a statement `if _N_ = 1 then put "id,name,semester,scoreEng";` after the `file` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also make use of ODS

```
ods listing file="C:\Users\1502911\Desktop\exportdata3.txt";
    proc print data=engappeal noobs;
    run;
ods listing close;
```

Comment: i just googled that i can employed csvall in ods to create the txt files too. Indeed what is the difference between listing, csv, csvall ?

Comment: ods csv - exports only tabular data                                                                       ods csvall - exports tabular data, header. footnote.,                                       ods listings - exports data as it must have been in listings if not exported to txt. like the space formats.,    Use all the three ods and try to export a dataset. you should be able to find out the difference. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the DSD option on the FILE statement to make sure that delimiters are properly quoted and missing values are not represented by spaces. Make sure you set your record length long enough, including delimiters and inserted quotes.  Don't worry about setting it too long as the lines are variable length.

You can use CALL VNEXT to find and output the names.  The LINK statement is so the loop is later in the data step to prevent __NAME__ from being included in the (_ALL_) variable list.

```
data _null_;
  set sashelp.class ;
  file 'class.csv' dsd dlm=',' lrecl=1000000 ;
  if _n_ eq 1 then link names;
  put (_all_) (:);
  return;
names:
  length __name__ $32;
  do while(1);
    call vnext(__name__);
    if upcase(__name__) eq '__NAME__' then leave;
    put __name__ @;
  end;
  put;
return;
run;
```